# How to get rid of instanceof check when using inheritance?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Assume we have a class Animal, with subclasses as cat, eagle

Now I have a method:

```
public void process(Animal animal) {

   if (animal instanceof Cat) {
     if (!animal.meow()) {
        throw exception("cat does not meow");
     } else {
      animal.feedFish();
     }
   }

   if (animal instanceof eagle) {
      if (!animal.fly()) {
         throw exception("eagle does not fly");
      } else {
        animal.checkMaxFlightAltitude();
      }
   }
}
```

Here cat has 2 methods `meow` and `feedfish` which are completely different than eagle's methods `fly` and `checkmaxflight`

Most design patterns revolve around assumptions that subclasses have a common method like Shape `draw()` inherited by circle `draw` and square `draw`

1. Is there some way to do validations on subclasses, such as cat and eagle without instanceof check ?
2. Any good design pattern ( assuming subclasses dont share a method in base class ? )

Comment: **Double dispatch**.

Comment: ^^ don't waste your time looking at Double dispatch, it is not an answer, and not even a good idea.  Your question contains the answer in its title: you can get rid of instanceof checks using inheritance.  You are currently *not* using inheritance.  Use inheritance and then all animals can have a "process()" method.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper It's actually what [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) is about!

Answer (score 7):

You could have an abstract `process` method in `Animal` and implement it in the subclasses:

```
class Animal {
  protected abstract void process();
  public static void process(Animal a) { a.process(); }
}

class Cat {
  void process() {
    if (!meow()) throw exception("cat does not meow");
    else feedFish();
  }
  public boolean meow() { ... }
  public void feedFish() { ... }
}
```

Comment: You could mention that this is called the *visitor* pattern.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm quite bad at naming patterns - is it really the visitor pattern?

Comment: I doubt that it is.

Comment: Well, sort of. Not exactly. Hmm. The full visitor pattern would expect that process() is called accept() instead; and takes some Visitor object parameter. Lets put it that way: having a process() method solves only half of the things that you want to address in the end.

Comment: @GhostCat It is NOT the visitor pattern!

Comment: Why would you have the public static dispatch method in there? You could make process() public abstract aswell right? Or did you do that for the sake of keeping the process(Animal) method that was there in the example?

Comment: @NickL Yes to your 2nd and 3rd question.

Answer (score 1):

This is when polymorphism comes in handy.

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract public void process(Animal animal);
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void process(Animal animal) {
        if (!this.meow()) {
            throw exception("cat does not meow");
        } else {
            this.feedFish();
        }
    }
}
class Eagle extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void process(Animal animal) {
        if (!this.fly()) {
            throw exception("eagle does not fly");
        } else {
            this.checkMaxFlightAltitude();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) by employing a [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Example:

```
public class Animal {
    public abstract void accept(AnimalVisitor v);

    public boolean meow() {return false;}
    public boolean fly() {return false;}
    public void feedFish() {};
    public void checkMaxFlightAltitude() {};

}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor v) {
        v.visitCat(this);
    }

    public boolean meow() {return true;}
}

public class Eagle extends Animal {
    public void accept(AnimalVisitor v) {
        v.visitEagle(this);
    }
    public boolean fly() {return true;}
}

public interface AnimalVisitor {
    void visitEagle(Eagle eagle);
    void visitCat(Cat cat);
}

public class AnimalVisitorExample implements AnimalVisitor {
    public void visitEagle(Eagle eagle) {
        eagle.checkMaxFlightAltitude();
    }

    public void visitCat(Cat cat) {
        cat.feedFish();
    }
}

Animal animal = new Cat();
animal.accept(new AnimalVisitorExample());
```

Comment: Why would animal have a fly method?

Comment: I was just following the example from the OP. I'm assuming there's no go reason for any of these methods apart from illustrating the question.

Comment: @massfords OP states that `meow()` and `feedFish()` belong to Cat while `fly()` and `checkMaxFlightAltitude()` belong to `Eagle`. When you pull this methods up into the superclass it defeats kind of the purpose of the visitor pattern. If you moved `feedFish()` and `checkMaxFlightAltitude()` to the corresponding classes leaving `accept()` as the only method in `Animal`, it would answer the question perfectly in my opinion.

Comment: I missed that in the comments. I assumed all of the methods were on Animal due to the lack of a cast when invoking them on Animal. Maybe this was an oversight in the OP or maybe it was just pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Is there some way to do validations on subclasses, such as cat and eagle without instanceof check ?

yes, there is. You could define a "validate" method (abstract in "Animal" class) and implement it in the specific subclasses. Depending on the validation result (e.g. exception / problem list) you can have the validate method throw some kind of "InvalidContentException" or provide the method call with an "ErrorHandler" that is informed about the bad things of an instance.

(2) assuming that the subclasses don't share a method in the base class: well, that one is a bit counter intuitive. On one hand you want to be able to do something on an "Animal", yet you don't want to define that capability on it?

You could define a Validator class that has separate validation methods (on for each kind of "Animal" subclass). That would eliminate the instanceof checks, however you would never be able to pass this Validator class other "Animals" (such as "Dog"), only "Cat" and "Eagle" (or subclasses thereof). You might also want to consider what you want to happen when passing subclasses of "Cat": are all sublasses of Cat validated in the same way or is there subclass specific behavior (like color, size, ...) for the different cat classes?

--> I think you should ask yourself if you want to be able to validate animals in general. Without having insight into your problem domain (which might have reasons not to do it), I'd recommend to have a "validate" method on the animal. You could also go for a visitor pattern, but that requires the Animal to have a "accept(AnimalVisitor visitor)" method and is slightly more code to write (presumably more than you want to)